# SQL Server Mgt Studio not showing table?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, ssms, database-security

I have a table in SQL Server 2000 Standard Edition called "dbo.T668" (don't blame me for the naming convention).

I'm working on the server using SQL Server Management Studio 2005, and for some strange reason, I can't see the table at all in the list of tables.  I see all the other tables, but not this one.

If I open up a query editor and type "select * from dbo.T668", it returns all the records, so I have permission to get to the table and select from it - is there a setting that allows you to get to the table but not see it in SQL Manager?  Or is this an incompatibility between SQL 2000 and SQL 2005?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it is a table and not a view?

Answer (score 2):

If you just created it recently make sure you hit the refresh button at the top, doesn't always seem to be in sync for me anyways.

Answer (score 0):

DOH!

Did a sp_help on it, and you're, right, it's a view.....there's like 2000 tables in this database, so I guess I just missed it.

Argh.